# Why do I have to create an AS3 package using Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, actionscript, namespaces, package

I know what "works"

If I create a new file in explorer named test.as and I create my packaged class, I haven't found a single way to have my flash file find and use it.  I've tried using relative and exact paths in the actionscript 3.0 settings.  It refuses to see it

However.  If I create an as3 class named "test" THROUGH the program, it actually "LOADS" the test.as that I created in explorer.  And has no problem finding and using the package.

I need to know why Flash requires that the .as file is made through it's program.

I feel like I'm entirely missing something.  Does this mean that if I want to use a class that I find in some tutorial.  I need to create new AS3 files and paste them in for each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to consider is that package names should always mirror folder structure.

Make sure that if you have a class declared as

`package com.mystuff { public class className {...} ...}`

that it is saved in "yourSoruceFolder/com/mystuff/className.as" and that when you reference it in your other code you import `com.mystuff;`

Make sure your class path includes the path to your "yourSoruceFolder" as well, if "yourSoruceFolder" is not your document root.

If you use the default package, aka `package { public class myClass ...}` without the `yourSoruceFolder`, then as long as the code is saved in the document root directory then it will work without additional folders, as you have seen in your testing.

Comment: This was the only answer that made sense to me.  Thank you

Comment: Yeah, I remember when I was figuring this same stuff out, seemed as though there was never a straight and simple answer on the internet as if I was expected to already know the relationship between folders and name-spaces. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: +1 the same system is used for Java. Anyone who's written Java in an IDE designed for it (like Eclipse) would note that whenever you declare a new package in your project directory, a new folder is generated and the java files for that package are contained within.